# What do you call the tendency to leave out important implicit assumptions in written communication?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, psycholinguistics

When we write to communicate something, often we miss out on certain details because we implicitly assume it to be obvious and that the reader would comprehend it without seeing it in words. Is there a word or a phrase to refer precisely to this human tendency?

Example usage quoted below:

> A common problem with communication is **unwritten assumptions**. Naturally, not everything in our mind gets translated to text. This leads to a sort of void in the reader's mind, which -- given the propensity of the human mind -- leads to "filling in" with assumptions of their own.
>
> We call this behaviour in human communication ____. The problem of ____ in communication can be mitigated by a number of ways:
>
> - by being explicit in communicating one's thoughts and ideas, leaving nothing 'assumed', albeit at the expense of being verbose
> - by [grounding](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/577014/102)

(The first paragraph of this example is actually from [this blog post](https://www.srid.ca/refactor-writing) of mine which might give addition context to the single-word-request.)

---

Perhaps there is a term in [psycholinguistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psycholinguistics) (specifically [language production](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_production)) to refer to this phenomenon?

### Related phrases

**EDIT 1:** Argument analysis is another field that could potentially help?

> when people present arguments, they do not always mention all of the beliefs which they hold which are pertinent unstated claims, the truth of which is a necessary condition of the argument’s working the way it should. People could not state everything pertinent to the argument in this way. They necessarily leave much unstated. Often **unstated assumptions** would be accepted by virtually everyone, and it would be a great bore for the arguer and the audience to spell them out. Sometimes arguers are not aware of their unstated assumptions; sometimes these assumptions are highly questionable, and neglecting to spell them out lulls the unwary audience into accepting things it would not have granted on critical scrutiny. It is often said that such unstated assumptions are the **missing premises** of the stated argument. https://ecampusontario.pressbooks.pub/wsia062018/chapter/5/

This is the key part from the quote above:

> Sometimes arguers are not aware of their unstated assumptions; [..] and neglecting to spell them out lulls the unwary audience into accepting things it would not have granted on critical scrutiny

This makes sense from logic/argumentation point of view, but applied to the more general communication (not argumentation) context, it would instead look like this:

> Sometimes writers are not aware of their unstated assumptions; [..] and neglecting to spell them out lulls the readers into assuming different things than the writer intended (and assumed)

And this is precisely what the word being requested here would refer to.

**EDIT 2**: [Implicit communication](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/implicit-confusion-explicit-clarity-ian-blei) (similar to [implicit assumption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_assumption)) seems to touch on the heart of the matter, though the phrase can mean [something else](https://sciencenordic.com/communication-society--culture/how-to-communicate-better-at-work/1455133).

Comment: Looking for *projection*?

Comment: [GoodTherapy](https://www.goodtherapy.org/blog/10-communication-problems-and-mistakes-we-all-make-0919157) lists 'failing to account for cultural differences in communication' as one common failing in (attempted) communication. Everybody has a diferent (sub-)culture. And we all make false assumptions about where the correct tension between being imprecise and being pedantic lies in individual conversations. // 'Assumed knowledge' has been defined as 'the minimum level of knowledge you need for a particular subject' (/ topic of conversation), but one also assumes certain opinions when chatting.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That may be one way of *explaining* its mechanisms (though I was referring to unwritten assumptions, not "false assumptions" per se). But what do we *call* this behaviour itself? It is a meta question.

Comment: Do you require a word meaning 'unwritten implicit assumptions in communication' or a word meaning 'the "filling in" with assumptions of their own of voids in the readers' minds because the material is non-comprehensive'?

Comment: A text can contains inferences and implications that are not stated....

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The former (but maybe I should include the latter as well). More precisely, I'm looking for a word that refers to this kind of "error" in communication, if you will.

Comment: @Lambie Hmm. Or 'unstated assumptions or 'missing premises' https://ecampusontario.pressbooks.pub/wsia062018/chapter/5/ 

(See post edit)

Comment: Correction: can contain. Sure, I was looking for two nouns.

Comment: I've edited the question to add further clarification based on the domain of argumentation analysis. Hopefully that's most clarifying.

Comment: It is a little unclear exactly what you're looking for. Is it the stuff that is missing/unspoken as in the title, or is it the tendency to leave it out as in the question in the first paragraph, or is it the tendency for the reader to fill in the left out stuff? Also, this seems like you're looking for a somewhat academic term and limiting the question to SWR is likely to leave out a more satisfying multi-word term. How come 'missing information', 'unstated assumptions', 'hidden agenda', or just plain 'context', which were all used in the question, not good enough as answers?

Comment: @Mitch Yea, I can see the confusion. I just edited the title (in the form of a full question) for clarity. It refers to the *tendency*. I'm not familiar 100% with this SE's policies, but in absence of a single-word, I'm willing to accept multi-word terms. Academic concepts are good, but any general word/term referring precisely to this tendency / communication-pattern is most welcome too.

Comment: The technical term for what you're looking for is [_Presupposition_](https://www.google.com/search?q=presupposition). There's an enormous literature on it in philosophy and linguistics, where it's not limited to writing, but extended to all speech. [Some common triggers for presuppositions](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/presuptrig.pdf), from Levinson.

Comment: @SridharRatnakumar OK, editing the title answers my question sort of (are you missing a preposition "...leave _out_..."?), but still leaves some clarity issues. The second sentence with a blank: "The problem of ____ in communication can be mitigated..." states that the term you're looking for is a problem, but the stated title term that is sought "A tendency to 'fill in'" is not.a problem by itself so it sounds strange to want to mitigate a tendency. Instead of looking for a word for this concept, you should rewrite the entire blog post and just use whatever multi-word phrase that fits best.

Comment: Uh, how about "normal"?

Comment: @Mitch. Yes, "leave out" ... fixed it; thanks. This behaviour may be acceptable or unacceptable, depending on the context.  It is acceptable in many cases, because concise communication is good. In some cases, where it leads to ambiguities in the reader, who in turn misinterprets (ie., "fill in") things, or gets offended - that's an area where it can be addressed/mitigated.

Comment: @JohnLawler As a presupposition is always taken for granted, [implicit assumption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_assumption) (which a presupposition is) looks to be more relevant here.

Answer (score 1):

> We call this behaviour in human communication *grounding*.

**Grounding**

> Grounding in communication is a concept proposed by Herbert H. Clark
> and Susan E. Brennan. It comprises the collection of "mutual
> knowledge, mutual beliefs, and mutual assumptions" that is essential
> for communication between two people. Successful grounding in
> communication requires parties "to coordinate both the content and
> process". The concept is also common in philosophy of language.
> [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grounding_in_communication)

> **Dialog acts and grounding**
>
> **Grounding** in dialog is the phenomenon that the participants in a conversation update their common ground, in particular adding elements
> to the perceived common ground. In Clark and Schaefer's classical
> model of **grounding**. (Clark and Schaefer 1989) participants in a dialogue try to establish
> for each utterance the mutual belief that the addressees have
> understood what the speaker meant.  [Yan Huang; *The Oxford Handbook
> of Pragmatics*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Oxford_Handbook_of_Pragmatics/FAjxDQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=grounding%20%22mutual%20knowledge%22&pg=PA337&printsec=frontcover)

As the word "coordinate" above implies, the concept applied to dialog entails a process of synchronization with feedback. For example you would probably start to add more explanatory detail, backtrack, or ask specifically about comprehension if the person you are speaking to furrows their brow or forehead in confusion as opposed to nodding to signify that they agree or  at least follow you.

In writing, an imperfect match between the writer's and the readers' *assumed* mutual knowledge can induce a translator to footnote a word judged to warrant an explanation.

Comment: thank you for this.  I had not heard of this notion, which is very appropriate for the specialist area of pragmatics (to which I am also an empty vessel.  I'm not sure, though, that it fits the context of the question, if only because the statement "I'm afraid your communication is ungrounded" would seem to mean that it was not properly justified by reasoned argument.  In general, also, the specialised use of the word 'grounding' is not exactly in line with dictionary definition [https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/grounded].  I wonder why a single word is needed.

Comment: The OP's tag is *psycholinguistics* and the example is "We call this behaviour in human communication ____." Why assume you can add "un" to any answer and have it necessarily make sense? If an answer were "common knowledge", you wouldn't say *uncommon knowledge*, but rather "Your communication assumes too much common knowledge."

Comment: However interesting this is, I think "grounding" is only a cognate word here. It is something that is utilized *after* this "error" in communication, and acts to address it. The word I'm looking for is to describe this "error" itself.

Comment: @SridharRatnakumar Your question is looking for a "Word **referring** to *unwritten implicit assumptions* in communication"

Comment: @DjinTonic That is correct; word referring to unwritten implicit assumptions (the 'error' itself), and not referring to the process people use (such as grounding) to address that error. (Another way to address the error is to just be explicit about everything).

Comment: @SridharRatnakumar So you mean *incorrect* assumptions. Most of our assumptions  about common knowledge are correct, which is why communication is possible. To assume something isn't in itself an error.

Comment: @DjinTonic I'd say - assumptions that are not written down, and thus leads the reader to assume *something else* (which in turn could even offend them, if not merely misinterpret the writer). 

Also I've edited the post to state the relation to your answer. Plus I added another relevance to argumentation/logic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130657/discussion-between-sridhar-ratnakumar-and-djintonic).

Answer (score 1):

Intuition and perception come to mind.

We call this behaviour in human communication **intuition/perception**.

> - intuition - "immediate apprehension or cognition" - [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intuition)

> - perception - "quick, acute, and intuitive cognition" - [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/perception)

Comment: Intuition does apply (take an upvote), but I think it is a far-ranging concept applying to more than unwritten assumptions.